# Can I use both one-to-one NAT and port mapping on one Watchguard FireBox?

Tags: watchguard

Old Watchguard III / 700.

Is it possible to do both port mapping and one-to-one NAT?

I recently changed ISP.  Our external static range is a different range from the gateway subnet.  Only way I could get it to work is to use one-to-one NAT for all my externally mapped IPs (maybe there's a way but I could not find it).

I had been using port mapping to create multiple services on the same external IP.  But I can't find a way to do that when one-to-one NAT is used for everything .

Is there a way?

Comment: I'm not quite understanding what you're asking. Are you asking if you can use port forwarding to forward specific traffic (services) from one public ip address to multiple internal ip addresses `AND` use 1-to-1 NAT for forwarding traffic from other public ip addresses to other internal ip addresses? If so, the answer is probably yes. I have a client who has an old Firebox III/1000 who does this.

Comment: Thank you;  I was doing exactly what you describe--successfully.